# Error: Could not find or main class (Java)

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgsPp.png)

get this error in the last 3-5 projects.
but I don't get the error when I copy the same codes to another project.
what is the reason of this?
I'm new in the programming world and this mistake started to annoy :(

Comment: https://hizliresim.com/grgn50 error picture

Comment: Don't post images of text, or your IDE. Copy/paste the relevant **text.**

Answer (score 0):

This error can have a couple of sources. I once wrote a blog post about it as I saw it so often on the NetBeans mailinglist:

> - Ensure you have a *public* class containing a main method
> - This class must have a well defined main method: “public static void main(String[] args) { }“
> - You have set up the project configuration with the correct class: Project Properties > Run > Main Class (maybe just set it again, so
>     that the project properties file is written again)
> - Try to rebuild the project: Menu > Run > Clean & Build Main Project
> - Still no success? Try renaming the class (Foo -> Foo1) and rename it back (Foo1 -> Foo). This should invalidate the NetBeans cache for this
>     file (Just assuming – I am not a NetBeans Developer).
> - Still no success?? You might to have to clear the NetBeans cache by deleting the directory “.netbeans6.8varcache” (the 6.8
>     might of course vary according to your version of NetBeans). Close
>     NetBeans before deleting the cache – the next start might take some
>     time as NB will most likely have to scan your code again.
> - Still no luck? You might want to consult the NetBeans user forum or nbusers-Mailinglist (please be friendly, patient and report the bug in
>     a way that others are able to help).

(copied from https://www.locked.de/no-main-class-found/ )